# Should I integrate Facebook SDK in my application when I can use iOS6 native Facebook integration

Tags: ios6, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

The requirement for my application is just Login and share an image to Facebook.

Is there any drawback to just work with native iOS6 integration only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The share of iOS5 across devices is very small (less then 10% of all iOS devices out there) so you are pretty safe to go with iOS6 integrated Facebook support; however, there is this very nice library https://github.com/sakrist/FacebookSample - you can use it (along with facebook sdk) to provide support for < iOS6 devices and is very easy to integrate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Lude. My target OS is iOS6 and above. I am just worried about conversion. Are users any apprehensive about using native Facebook integration? Will I get better conversion if I include Facebook Application login?

Comment: For one of our apps we did added both options. Many people were used to FB App (at that time it was so) and we wanted to make it easier for them; but it didn't went without a lot of confusion, because you can have different accounts logged in in FB App and Native FB, some of our users were expecting to log in with the account from their FB App; but ending with Native FB account being linked in. I would suggest going this way, providing both options; but be careful with the implementation. :)